# How to get values from nested array of objects - React JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to the values from my data.json which consists of array of objects. I am trying to get the values by using map method on json data. My Json dat structure is like Array->Object->Array-Object([{[{}]}]). This is how the data is structured in Json. I have written down the Json data and logic to get the values down. Whenever I am trying to get the values from (inner array of object) I am ending up with undefined. Any one could assist me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

```
[
  {
    "key": "row-0",

    "cells": [
      {
        "key": "cell-0",
        "id": "ID-0",
        "headerName": "Name",
        "CustomerName": "ABC"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-1",
        "id": "ID-1",
        "headerName": "RegID",
        "CustomerID": "P-01"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-2",
        "id": "ID-2",
        "headerName": "Detail",
        "Deatil": "Abc"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "key": "row-1",

    "cells": [
      {
        "key": "cell-1",
        "id": "ID-1",
        "headerName": "Name",
        "CustomerName": "CDE"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-2",
        "id": "ID-2",
        "headerName": "RegID",
        "CustomerID": "P-02"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-3",
        "id": "ID-3",
        "headerName": "Detail",
        "Deatil": "CDE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

//Logic

```
{mockData.map((values, index) => {
        console.log("VALUES", values);
        return values.cells.map(({ headerName, ...rest }) => {
          console.log("JSON", JSON.stringify(rest));
          console.log("REST", rest.CustomerName);---> getting undefined(I tried many approach everything is giving me undefined)
        });
      })}
```

Comment: the elements without CustomerName give undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example for you

As mentioned in the above comment.. elements without customerName will give undefined.

```js
let mockData = [{
    "key": "row-0",

    "cells": [{
        "key": "cell-0",
        "id": "ID-0",
        "headerName": "Name",
        "CustomerName": "ABC"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-1",
        "id": "ID-1",
        "headerName": "RegID",
        "CustomerID": "P-01"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-2",
        "id": "ID-2",
        "headerName": "Detail",
        "Deatil": "Abc"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "key": "row-1",

    "cells": [{
        "key": "cell-1",
        "id": "ID-1",
        "headerName": "Name",
        "CustomerName": "CDE"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-2",
        "id": "ID-2",
        "headerName": "RegID",
        "CustomerID": "P-02"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-3",
        "id": "ID-3",
        "headerName": "Detail",
        "Deatil": "CDE"
      }
    ]
  }
];


mockData.map((values, index) => {
  console.log("VALUES", values);
  return values.cells.map(({
    headerName,
    ...rest
  }) => {
    console.log("JSON",rest);
    console.log("Key:", rest.key);
    console.log("ID:", rest.id);
    console.log("CustomerName:", rest.CustomerName ? rest.CustomerName : 'NA' );
    
  });
})
```